# Ubuntu 16.04 hibernation resume with clean state

Tags: boot, 16.04, hibernate

Previously, hibernate works just fine but for some reason it doesn't work now. I can't recall if I ever made any changes except like a normal update through `apt update`.

I have check numerous posts here and it seems I have the right settings.

```
$  sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="e85c308d-b4e1-443d-aeed-6d4bfd799ec3" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="7eca3ee4-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0LzBCw-x2TE-b9jI-h5Pe-V8ks-G6tZ-sGWN07" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="7eca3ee4-05"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="97be0519-c15f-46b0-a283-56fc2a95d143" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="39f2a6c3-1fe9-41f8-a825-ec873d6347e3" TYPE="swap"

$  sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7eca3ee4

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 976771071 975769602 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 976771071 975769600 465.3G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 453.6 GiB, 487025803264 bytes, 951222272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 11.7 GiB, 12566134784 bytes, 24543232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

$  sudo lsblk                                  
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5                  8:5    0 465.3G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  11.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 453.6G  0 lvm  /
└─sda1                  8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
```

On reboot, it usually display following messages right after resuming from hibernate, I can't recall the exact messages but it is something along the line `Recovering journal.. clearing inode...`

My `initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` has the following value,

```
RESUME=UUID=39f2a6c3-1fe9-41f8-a825-ec873d6347e3
```

My `fstab` has,

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=e85c308d-b4e1-443d-aeed-6d4bfd799ec3 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

My `grub` file has the following settings,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet resume=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1"
```

`by-uuid` also doesn't have reference to my swap

```
$  ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Oct 15 14:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 Oct 15 14:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 15 14:35 97be0519-c15f-46b0-a283-56fc2a95d143 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 15 14:35 e85c308d-b4e1-443d-aeed-6d4bfd799ec3 -> ../../sda1
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04,

```
$  uname -a
Linux shulhi-thinkpad 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and in system monitor, it doesn't show my swap partition.

[image]